# syncfusion scheduler only starts to show events only after one month of the StartTime

Tags: syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Trying to use sycfusion vue scheduler but when looking at docs example
[link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/schedule/appointments/#creating-a-recurring-event)

This is the event data from the example in docs which has `StartTime` as `January 15th 2008`

```
let data = [{
Id: 1,
Subject: 'Paris',
StartTime: new Date(2018, 1, 15, 10, 0),
EndTime: new Date(2018, 1, 15, 12, 30),
IsAllDay: false,
RecurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5'
}];
```

But in preview events are showing after one month from the `StartTime` on `February 15th` instead of `january`. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bug - months in the `Date` object are 0-indexed, so it works properly.

```
new Date(2018, 1, 15, 10, 0) // Thu Feb 15 2018 10:00:00
new Date(2018, 0, 15, 10, 0) // Mon Jan 15 2018 10:00:00
```

More about Date object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#examples)